# Unable to see the form data in console after clicking the button,angular2

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular

I created a simple login form with which i use to see the input data in my console but i am getting an empty object.Can any one help me out where the error is

My template,

```
 <div class="login jumbotron center-block">
 <h1>Login</h1>
<form  #form ="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" ngControl ="email" class="form-control" id="emailh" placeholder="Username">
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password"  ngControl ="phone" class="form-control" id="phoneh" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button   class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

 </form>
   <a  [routerLink]="['/demo/signup']" >Sign Up</a>

      <div class="col-md-9">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
   </div>
```

My component,

```
     import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
     import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
     import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
     import { contentHeaders } from '../headers/headers';
     import {FORM_DIRECTIVES,FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({

  directives:   [CORE_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,FORM_DIRECTIVES,REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl : "./components/login/login.html",

 })
export class Login {

 constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
 }

onSubmit(form:any) {

 console.log(form);
        }
        }
```

Comment: [install Prefix](http://www.prefix.io/), it may help you see the problem and it will definitely help in general.

Comment: Hi Crowcoder will it work for angular since it shows for .net

Comment: It works with ASP.net as an http handler so it doesn't matter if it is angular or anything else. Are you using ASP.net? I guess I just assumed.

Comment: i am not sure about that

Comment: What angular version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular2 rc4 here is my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
     ...........
}
```

and I updated your code in my project, and it is working like a charm. Update your code like below -

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm"  
          (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)"  
          class="ui form">

      <div class="form-group"  
          [class.error]="!email.valid && email.touched">  
        <label for="emailInput">Email</label>  
        <input type="text"  
               id="emailInput"  
               placeholder="EMAIL"  
               [formControl]="email">  

      </div>
      <div>
         <!-- Do it for password too !-->
      </div>


      <div *ngIf="!myForm.valid"  
        class="ui error message">Form is invalid</div>

      <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>  
 </form>
```

Hope , It works for you. Actually it will :)